# Null Value for nameArr in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null value for nameArr  in the following source code and I'm not sure why.

When I attempt to use the following:

```
System.out.println("testing123");
System.out.println(nameArr);
```

I’m getting:

```
08-07 19:51:53.540: I/System.out(1048): testing123
08-07 19:51:53.540: I/System.out(1048): []
```

It it appears it’s null at this point – any suggestions?

I'm really not sure why this is happening.

SOURCE:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
    private Button mUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    public static XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    private NetworkTask task;
    private AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateActivity";
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
        int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
        task = new NetworkTask();
        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();

        handler.setContext(ctx);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
                || (phoneType != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
                        && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE)) {
            // If the phone type is CDMA or
            // the phone phone type is not GSM and the network type is none of
            // the network types indicated in the statement
            // Display incompatibility message
            showAlert(getString(R.string.incomp_sm_dialog));
            // Network type is looked because some tablets have no phone type.
            // We rely on network type in such cases
        } else if (!(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                || (tm.getSimOperator())
                        .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo)) || (tm
                    .getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att)))) {
            // if SIM is present and is NOT a T-Mo network SIM,
            // display Error message alert indicating to use SM SIM
            showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        }// No SIM or SIM with T-Mo MNC MCC present
        else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            // Initial UI setup for versions lower than ICS
            setContentView(R.layout.update);
            mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);

            mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {// ICS and up

            // task.execute();

            if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                            .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                // Update APN table in separate thread
                task.execute("");

                // Device has T-Mo network SIM card MCC and MNC correctly
                // populated
                // Reduce number of steps to 6
                TotalSteps = 6;
            }
            //
            // Initial UI setup for ICS and up

        //  setContentView(R.layout.updating);



            // String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_cta2);
            // CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            // xtView assistText = (TextView)
            // findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            // sistText.setText(styledText);
            // mAssistUpdateButton = (Button)
            // findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            //mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == mUpdateButton) {
            // Update button for versions lower than ICS is selected
            // setContentView(R.layout.updating);
            onClickMethod(v);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {
            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            // Create ConfigActivity Intent
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
            // go back to 1st set of instructions if read again is selected
            mInstructionNumber = 0;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
            String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_cta2);
            CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onClickMethod(View v) {
        mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_update_active_hdpi);

    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        UpdateActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        mConfirmAlert = builder.create();
        mConfirmAlert.show();
    }
    // AsyncTask to call web service
        private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStream> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    // saving the response in InputStream
                    stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-rsp-eng.xml");
                //  stream = new BufferedInputStream(https.getInputStream());
                           DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                             String strLine; 
                               while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content on the console 
                               System.out.println (strLine); 
                                     in.close();
                               }


                } catch (IOException e) {

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // The code below plays a Simple Promo animation

                for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                    // Sleep for 1/2 second
                    // Invoke UI to change updating text to show 1 dot
                    // And Increasing the level to reduce the amount of clipping and
                    // slowly reveals the hand image
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                    }
                    publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                            R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                    // Sleep for 1/2 second
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                    }
                }
                return stream;
            }

            /*
             * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
             * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
             */
            protected synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(String urlQueryString)
                    throws IOException, SAXException, SSLException,
                    SocketTimeoutException, Exception {
                // HttpsURLConnection https = null;


                HttpsURLConnection https = null;
                String uri = urlQueryString;

                URL urlo = new URL(uri);

                try {
                    https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
                    https.setConnectTimeout(20000); // 20 second timeout
                    https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                    if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                        stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
                    } else
                        stream = https.getInputStream();

                } catch (SSLException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    // https.disconnect();
                }

                return stream;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

                // Call function to update image view

                setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1]);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
                super.onPostExecute(stream);
    // This method is called to parse the response and save the ArrayLists
                success();

            }

        }

        private void setProgressImgView(Integer textViewId, Integer imageViewId) {
            // update image view with the updating dots
            // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
            //setContentView(R.layout.updating);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestart() {
            super.onRestart();

            if (mErrorAlert != null)
                mErrorAlert.dismiss();
        }


        public void success() {

            // to parse the response
            try {
                handler.getQueryResponse(stream);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // to set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
            setArrayList();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
        // method to save the ArrayLists from parser
                public static void setArrayList() {
        //nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
        nameArr.addAll(handler.getnameArr());
        ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        count = handler.getCount();
        System.out.println("testing123");
        System.out.println(nameArr);

        }
    }
```

Handler Source: (hosted on google docs - it exceeds the character limit for this post)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rosp9zM0RmFyBZVWaXaHJeLAITWiM2ziAU_JR9eNRzg/edit?usp=sharing

P.S.

I'm getting a null pointer error on the line:

```
String value = Values.get("name").toString();
```

LOGCAT:

```
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.showNotification(ConfigFinalActivity.java:509)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.onClick(ConfigFinalActivity.java:620)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-07 21:30:24.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1998):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 21:30:28.750: I/Process(1998): Sending signal. PID: 1998 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Does anything actually get added into nameArr? I've looked through your code a few times and really don't see any reference to that variable outside of the initial declaration and in setArrayList()

Comment: Stop using so many global variables.  Name your stuff something meaningful.  You should never declare things like NameArr, nameArr... so on.  Also think long and hard about why you need 10 different global arraylists, is there a better solution? Maybe a class to encapsulate the data?

Answer (score 7):

> It it appears it’s null at this point – any suggestions?

No, it's not `null`. It is an empty list (size = 0).

---

Side note: Having a variable named `nameArr` and a variable named `NameArr` is very confusing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for pointing that out! :) Any idea why it's appearing blank (or what I can do to resolve it?)

Comment: [again] - It's NOT appearing "blank", it's appearing "[]" - empty list.

Comment: @DroidZilla: sure, `add()` some items to your list before printing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
nameArr.addAll(handler.getnameArr());
```

This is the place you are adding to this Arraylist named "nameArr".

Perhaps checking what `handler.getnameArr()` is returning might give you clues.
Note that its not returning null , it is returning an empty Collection.

Comment: Any idea why it's appearing blank (or what I can do to resolve it?)

Comment: @DroidZilla :if you check your method  ` public ArrayList<String> getnameArr() {
                System.out.println("testing123");
                return  nameArr;                                             
                  
        }`  , Here you are actually returning the same arraylist which you created at the top ,which is empty (that is its just initialized but does not contain any elements  . If you do nameArr.add("testing123") , this will add String element to this arraylist nameArr.

Comment: public ArrayList<String> getnameArr() {
  System.out.println("test");
  System.out.println(nameArr); 
  nameArr.add("testing123");
  return nameArr;

Did not seem to resolve the null pointer issue - I'm still getting a null pointer @ String value = Values.get("name").toString();

Comment: @DroidZilla : check what is null , is the object "Values" null? or Values.get("name") is null? looking at the code , i suspect that you dont need to invoke toString() on this Values.get("name") since it is returning you a string.

Comment: Values is appearing null - also when I attempt to use String value = values.get("name"); eclipse spits out a "Type Mismatch Error: Cannot Convert From Object To String"

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: @DroidZilla: Values is empty , perhaps the way you are initializing might be incorrect instead of doing public  ContentValues Values = new ContentValues(); should you do this ContentValues Values = getContentValues();? getContentValues should be static  i am not sure of the functionality you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `nameArr=handler.getnameArr();` to `nameArr.addAll(handler.getnameArr());` in order to add all the results to the array list

Comment: I attempted your solution (updated source above) but I'm still getting  08-07 20:32:48.942: I/System.out(1371): [] in my logcat

Comment: you'll have to post the code of handler class then, what is supposed to be in the array?

Comment: I added it above... it can be found here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rosp9zM0RmFyBZVWaXaHJeLAITWiM2ziAU_JR9eNRzg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If the value of nameArr were null, System.out.println would say "null", not "[]".  So what you have there is an empty list.

Comment: Any idea why it's appearing blank (or what I can do to resolve it?)

Comment: It's NOT appearing "blank", it's appearing "[]" - empty list.

Comment: From looking at the code - hopefully I'm looking at the right place - you are defining a variable nameArr about 3 lines into the UpdateActivity class and initalizing it to an empty ArrayList.  I didn't find any code in your classes that changed the contents of that ArrayList, so that's why it's empty.  Most IDE's include a step debugger that let you put a watch on variables or fields to break when their values change.  You might try doing that and seeing if anything ever adds any Strings to that ArrayList after it's initialized.